# Determine initial permeability from experimental data

Tags: electromagnetism, measurement-problem, experimental-technique

How to determine initial permeability of the sample having only its dimensions (ring with $R$ - external radius, $r$ - internal radius, and thickness $h$), the number of coils around it $N$, and only information about voltage, that it comes from oscillator level of $0.5V$. All of these are supported by experimental data of real, and imaginary parts of permeability dependent on frequency.